# Jekyll websites aren't loading templates correctly

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I cannot use Jekyll correctly; for any post, if I try to view my site in the browser, I only see Markdown. The generated HTML is only from the Markdown, meaning that the templates (from the `_layouts`) folder aren't working correctly. Can somebody point out the issue that's causing this to not work?

Here are the files I'm working with:

- [My Base layout file for Jekyll](http://pastebin.com/uS1zywjy)
- [My Post layout file for Jekyll](http://pastebin.com/VU0ZTftP)
- I'm using the default Jekyll post (the one that comes out of the box)
- I haven't touched my `_config` YAML file.

I'm working on a Win 8.1 machine with Ruby 1.9.3 and Jekyll 1.4.2. I appreciate any help you guys can provide; I just really hope I can use this tool, it seems perfect for my needs.

**Edit**: Here's some more information about my set-up:

My base layout file (the one that contains the HTML head and parts of the body) is default.html. My folder scheme is the same as the one shown in the documentation. The site was made from the one auto created when the command `jekyll new ____` is issued.

Oh, and here's the front matter:

From the post:

```
    ---
    layout: post
    title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
    date:   2014-03-13 20:22:46
    categories: jekyll update
    ---
```

From the post.html template:

```
     ---
     layout: default
     ---
```

From the default.html template:

```
     ---
     ---
```

Comment: You did this with no errors? http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/

Comment: Yes. I had to adjust the version of Ruby I used (from 2 to 1.9.3) because Jekyll didn't work with 2, and the version of Jekyll I used (from 1.4.3 to 1.4.2).

Comment: Your folder structure looks like this: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/ ?

Comment: Is your "Base" layout called "default.html"? What is the head matter of your post?

Comment: My folder structure is the same as the one in the docs, and I've posted additional details to the OP.

Comment: When you view your site in your browser, what address is in URL bar? For instance, does it say something like `file:///`, or something like `localhost:4000` or `http://0.0.0.0:4000/`?

Comment: @nicksuch `localhost:4000` is precisely what I see. The few times I was able to get Jekyll to work, it wouldn't render anything else correctly either (even with the preloaded theme). I switched to a Linux VM and it works just fine - can I put that as the answer to the question?

Comment: @user2254 Glad to hear it's working with Linux! It sounds more like you're having an issue with Windows/Ruby/Jekyll setup, not Jekyll templates. Have you tried [PortableJekyll](http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2013/07/20/buildportablejekyll.html)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I love using Jekyll, although I haven't looked into PortableJekyll. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though, I truly appreciate it!